# Find and sum mysql fields from a specific pattern

Tags: php, mysql

I have in a mysql table the number of downloads for a specific file.

I use the following code to fetch the number of downloads:

```
<?php $debname = 'com.dev.package_1.0-1_iphoneos-arm.deb'; ?>  

<?PHP include("../../config.php");
$query = "SELECT stats FROM download WHERE filename =  '".$debname."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[0];
}
?>
```

Sometimes, i update the packages and the name of the new package will be changed, for example: `com.dev.package_2.1-1_iphoneos-arm.deb`

This will then make the page display the counts of the new package which are reset to 0

Therefore, I'm trying to find a way to get the total number of downloads for all the versions

For example:

```
filename                                |     stats
________________________________________|_________________
com.dev.package_1.0-1_iphoneos-arm.deb  |       25
com.dev.package_2.1-1_iphoneos-arm.deb  |       2
________________________________________|_________________
Total Downloads of com.dev.package      |       27
```

So I want to display on my page the sum of the 2 file which is 27

Comment: Are you looking for just the one number? Or do you want an output like you show in your example? If it is the latter you will want to use a crosstab query.

Comment: i am looking to find the number 27 which is the sum of the 2 filenames, so i'm basically trying to find all the filename starting with `com.dev.package` and count their stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
$query = "SELECT sum(stats) AS sum FROM download WHERE filename LIKE '%com.dev.package%'";


echo $row[sum];
```

Comment: this will sum if the filename are equal which is not the case

Comment: oh i'm sorry in that case you want Jay's above. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: what type are your fields in your DB? `string` or `int` ?

Comment: the stats field are set to `int(11)`

Comment: remove the `GROUP BY` and also add single quotes to the words `sum`

Comment: nice it worked, that's the final code `$query = "SELECT sum(stats) AS sum FROM download WHERE filename LIKE '%com.dev.package%'";` if you want, you can edit your answer to accept it :)

Comment: glad i could be of help

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the individual stats for each of the products (edited to meet upwith OP's comments) -

```
SELECT sum(`stats`) AS `Stats` 
FROM `download` 
WHERE `filename` 
LIKE '%com.dev.package%'
```